# Two (non compatible) ways of describing the locus $\{ z(\overline{z}+2)=3: z \in \mathbb{C}\}$ Which one is wrong?

Tags: complex-numbers

**Problem:** Describe the locus  $\mathcal{L}$ determined by the equation
$$z(\overline{z}+2)=3, z \in \mathbb{C}.$$

**My argument:**
Let $z=x+iy$. We compute as follows:

$$(x+iy)(x-iy+2)=3;$$
$$(x^2+2x+y^2)+(2y)i=3;$$

equaling the real and imaginary parts, we get the system of equations
\begin{cases}
  x^2+2x+y^2=3\\
  2y=0
\end{cases}

Solving it, I conclude that  $\mathcal{L}=\{(-3,0),(1,0)\}$.

**Person B's argument:** By completing squares in the equation
$$(x^2+2x+y^2)+(2y)i=3$$
they get
$$(x+1)^2+(y+i)^2=3.$$
*Person B's conclusion:* the locus is the circumference with center $(-1, -i)$ and radius 3^(1/2).

Now, I don't even understand what their conclusion means. How can a circumference in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$) have the point $(-1, -i) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{C}$ as its center? Person B argued that "since we are working with complex numbers we can work with complex coordinates", but for me this as wrong as talking about a complex number with real or imaginary part being a complex number as well (instead of a real number).

**My question:** Is Person B's argument wrong? How will you make Person B realize their mistake?

Comment: @DonThousand a way of constructing $\mathbb{C} $ is by defining a sum and a product on the set  $\mathbb{R}  \times \mathbb{R} $; a complex number has a unique representation as an ordered pair $(a,b)$ with $a$ and $b$ *real numbers*.

Comment: I'm aware. I've seen $(a,b)$ written as $(a,bi)$ sometimes. Can't say I like the notation, but it does exist.

Comment: The essential failure in the second argument is that Person B has expanded the domain of $x$ and $y$. When we say 'let $z=x+iy$' there's an implicit assumption that $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$; otherwise we can't assign each $z$ to a unique $x,y$ pair. So while $(x+1)^2+(y+i)^2=3$ _is_ a correct way of writing the equation that you get, we have to restrict $x$ and $y$ to be in $\mathbb{R}$ — and that takes us back to the first solution.

Comment: What happened to the $-ixy$ term?

Comment: @steven -- Feel the rhythm, feel the rhyme, get on up! It's answer time! Would like to see your comment so converted.

Answer (score 1):

As $z(\bar z+2)$ is real it equals its conjugate $\bar z(z+2)$ from which $\bar z=z$ follows. Solving $z(z+2)=3$ gives $z=-3$ or $z=1$.